# How to get the screen refresh rate using Xlib

Tags: c, linux, xlib

I'm looking for Xlib function or macro that will give me actual screen's refresh rate. Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: currently I use glXGetMscRateOML function from GLX_OML_sync_control extension but NVIDIA driver doesn't support GLX_OML_sync_control extension so I need to fallback to more general mechanism. Do you have any problem with it, Mike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a quick search tells me it's not possible directly with xlib. However it seems possible using the XRandR extension, with the function [`XRRConfigRates`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xrrconfigrates).